# Adding a new "Sort by" in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, sorting, magento

Actually we just need sort by name ascending and descending.
My atribute is "name" so i did this in `/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` :

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
            if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) 
        {
            if(($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'name')    
                { 
                    $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('name','desc');
                } 
                /*
            else if(($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'name','asc') 
                { 
                    $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('name','asc'); 
                }*/
            else 
                {
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
                }
        }
    return $this;
}
```

adding this is always repeated in several guides, sadly most skip naming folders and files but it works as long as the `else if (asc)` part is commented out.
How can i add a second name for ascending?

Comment: Can you explain further what logic you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually... i can't. Our responsible Guy for this part went into exile and i dont know what iam doing! But by fumbling around i got accidently a step ahead. Under Catalogue/ manage Atributes i renamed name to Ascending, and created another Attribute named Descending. After writing those into the code above Magento started working!

Answer (score 1):

Please go to following path in admin panel 
Catalog -> Attributes ->Manage Attributes -> Search your attribute 'name' in below the Attribute code column.Click Search button.Click on your attribute name.Then edit 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' option as 'Yes'. And save Attribute.

See the screen short below. It may help you.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgpDv.png)